# Ebay API JSON request

Tags: json, ebay-api

I am new to eBay API .I using JSON format for request and reply.
Can any give me working sample (html file) using  JSON( API call findItemsByKeywords)
I am basically having trouble in getting the results.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make this HTTP request:

```
http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords
   &SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0
   &SECURITY-APPNAME=YOUR_APP_ID_HERE
   &RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON
   &REST-PAYLOAD
   &keywords=harry%20potter%20phoenix
```

Source: [eBay Finding API Making an API Call](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/Concepts/MakingACall.html)